# IN APP Purchase how to retrieve monthly subscription

Tags: android, payment

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "subs", null);
                            int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
                             if (response == 0) {

                                ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
                                ArrayList<String> purchaseDataList =
                                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
                                ArrayList<String> signatureList =
                                        ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
                                String continuationToken =
                                        ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

//
                                if(purchaseDataList.size() == 0){
                                    paid = false;
                                    App.paid = false;
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit();
                                    editor.putString("paid", "");
                                    editor.commit();
                                }
                                for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
                                    String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                                    String signature = signatureList.get(i);
                                    String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);
                                    try {
                                        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                                        String sku1 = jo.getString("productId");
                                        if (sku1.trim().toLowerCase().equals("paid2")) {
                                            paid = true;
                                            App.paid = true;
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit();
                                            editor.putString("paid", "1");
                                            editor.commit();

                                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {
                                                    try {
                                                        stopAds();
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }, 2000);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            paid = false;
                                            App.paid = false;
                                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit();
                                            editor.putString("paid", "");
                                            editor.commit();
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        //   alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

The idea behind this is, I have monthly subscription I want to retrieve if he is subscribed to it or not.  If he is subscribed i put  sharedpreference paid as 1, if not "".

Is this way to do? what if i buy right now, do i get it right way? what if i cancel subscription..do i get in list or not anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) manual you can detect whether user is subscribed using 
`getBuyIntent()` .

It yields `purchaseState = 0`.

I just only suggest to detect the state each time when the user launches the app. 
You can manually set the time lenght of subscription in `developerPayload`.
I would recommend not to use sharedpreferences. Or secure your data using encription in order to protect your app.